# Pytest pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError due to the pytest-json-report plugin

Tags: pytest

I use `pytest` together with the `pytest-json-report` plugin. I have the `pytest_json_modifyreport` hook in the `conftest.py` file.

When I run the command `pytest --json-report`, it is OK. But when I run the simple `pytest` command, it yields the following: `pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_json_modifyreport' in plugin`.

Is it possible to get rid of that error without commenting out the hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/numirias/pytest-json-report#a-note-on-hooks):

**A note on hooks**

If you're using a pytest_json_* hook although the plugin is not installed or
not active (not using --json-report), pytest doesn't recognize it and may fail with an internal error like this:

```
INTERNALERROR> pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_json_runtest_metadata' in plugin <module 'conftest' from 'conftest.py'>
```

You can avoid this by declaring the hook implementation optional:

```py
import pytest
@pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
def pytest_json_runtest_metadata(item, call):
    ...
```