# pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html_results_table_header' in plugin <module 'conftest'

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run Pytest on Windows 10 machine but getting below error:

```
Collecting ... collected 1 item
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 270, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 323, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 493, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 115, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 152, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 114, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise exc.with_traceback(exc.__traceback__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 77, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 334, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 666, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     self.config.pluginmanager.check_pending()
INTERNALERROR>   File "E:\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 370, in check_pending
INTERNALERROR>     raise PluginValidationError(
INTERNALERROR> pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html_results_table_header' in plugin <module 'conftest' from 'E:\\conftest.py'>
```

I am using below libraries :

```
selenium==4.12.0
pytest==7.2.2
chromedriver-py==116.0.5845.96
pytest-html-reporter==0.2.9
logging==0.4.9.6
postpy2==0.0.8
```

As per thread [Pytest pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError due to the pytest-json-report plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913773/pytest-pluggy-manager-pluginvalidationerror-due-to-the-pytest-json-report-plugi) I hv added below code but still no success.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
def  pytest_json_runtest_metadata(item, call):
```

Comment: any follow up on this ? :)